# Numerical method to find an upper bound linear function of bounded scalar function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

> Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar function. How can I find a good upper linear function $y(x) = mx+n$ such that $f(x) \leq y(x)$ for all $x\in [a, b]$?

Assume that $f$ is continuous and bounded.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What is your definition of **good**? What are the properties of $f$ (continuous, differentiable, monotone etc)?

Comment: OK, you can take any but it is not too far away from $f$. $f$ is continuous and bounded.

Comment: But you still need to define what a good upper function is. Do you need $\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |y(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ or $\int_a^b |y-f|^p<\varepsilon$ for some $p\in[1,\infty)$ or something else?

Comment: For continuous $f$ the trivial solutions is $m=0, n=\max(f(x)).$ 
For better estimates we need a definition of **good** and more properties of $f$

Answer (score 0):

You can't because $f(.)$ can become unbounded, even though its domain is compact.  For example $f(x)=1/(b-x)$ if $x \ne b$ and $0$ if $x = b$  There are no real numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $f(x) \le n + mx$ on $[a,b]$.

A continuous real-valued function on a compact domain is automatically bounded. So the second assumption is redundant.  Let $M$ be its maximum.  Then $y(x)=M$ is a simple linear function satisfying $f(x) \le y(x)$.  But you probably want more than that!

Comment: Firsher  I change my assumption.